# What's another word for 'constitution' that conveys a similar meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word similar to constitution but in the context of an organization or team rather than a country. Basically a document that a team collaborates on and whenever they want to make a revision or amendment it has to go through intense discussion and review first (so, similar to when a court has to debate before an amendment to a constitution is applied). Furthermore, this document outlines everything the organization or team needs to know (i.e. institutional knowledge) (similar to how a constitution might outline everything a citizen needs to know to live in their country).

Edit: To add more ideas.... in my mind it's a document that's continually updated to reflect the current consensus of a group of people.

Comment: Google `synonym constitution`

Comment: Of course I've already tried that @HotLicks

Comment: Depending on the organisation there might also be specific technical terms; for instance, a limited company in the UK has Articles of Association.

Comment: @wooooo298103 - And you didn't notice that "charter" is the very first word that shows up?

Comment: @HotLicks guess not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Charter* would be a good choice,

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/charter):

> A written constitution or description of an organization's functions.
>
> ‘the impending review of the BBC's Charter’

From the [American Hertiage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=charter)

> A document outlining the principles, functions, and organization of a
>   corporate body; a constitution: the city charter.

Comment: I really like this answer, I might accept it

Comment: @wooooo298103 It's a solid answer. I would accept it. :-)

Comment: There is also "Mission Statement" although this seems to be losing favour.

Comment: @RichardKayser done

Comment: @wooooo298103 Good!